# Upper semi-continuity with respect to inclusion

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

A mapping $\Lambda:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is said to be upper semi-continuous with respect to inclusion(u.s.c.i) at $\left(t_0,x_0\right)$, where, $t_0\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ if for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
\begin{equation}
\Lambda\left(t,x\right)\subseteq \left[\Lambda\left(t_0,x_0\right)\right]_{\epsilon}
\end{equation}
for every $\left(t,x\right)$ in $\delta-$ neighborhood of $\left(t_0,x_0\right)$. and $[U]_{\epsilon}$ represents closed $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $U$.

My doubt comes in this second part mentioned below:

"The mapping is said to be u.s.c.i. on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ if it is u.s.c.i. at every point of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$".

Since the mapping of all points ( and these points may be in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$) in the $\delta-$ neighborhood of $\left(t_0,x_0\right)$ lie inside the $\epsilon-$ neighborhood of mapping of $\left(t_0,x_0\right)$, then clearly, for all these points inside $B\left((t_0,x_0),\delta\right)$, barring $(t_0,x_0)$, the requirement for u.s.c.i. is not satisfied, unless the $\subseteq$ sign is replaced with $=$. Otherwise, it is not possible that $\Lambda$ will be u.s.c.i. on every part of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Can someone explain in detail, the meaning of sentence written in quotes.

Comment: It seems $\Lambda$ is perhaps meant to be $\mathcal P(\mathbb R^{n+1}) \to \mathcal P(\mathbb R^m)$?

Comment: Here is the definition of u.s.c.i. by the author:
http://books.google.com/books?id=3OZj3uPG3isC&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=upper+semicontinuous+with+respect+to+inclusion+berkovitz&source=bl&ots=a57nnRfRt5&sig=YWdBp1BhwKsSD-2JKN_ZbQ8QCEM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FI1ZVM65JdeyyASUr4KIDQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=upper%20semicontinuous%20with%20respect%20to%20inclusion%20berkovitz&f=false

Comment: So it seems $\Lambda : \mathbb R^{n+1} \to \mathcal P (\mathbb R^m)$.

Comment: I am new to analysis. What does $\mathcal{P}$ denote?

Comment: The power set. In words, $\Lambda$ maps elements of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ to *subsets* of $\mathbb R^m$.